# SQL- Joining tables and checking if something exists not working/incorrect syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, join, phpmyadmin

I am trying to write an sql statement in phpmyadmin.

I have three tables - one tables has all of the data from my posts with a unique ID of `wp_posts.ID.`

The other table is a tags table that has a list of tags that can be added to posts. Each tag has a unique tag id called `term_taxonomy_id.`

The last table is a relationship table that only creates a record if a tag has been added to a post. This has a unique ID called `Object_ID`. This `Object_ID` will be equal to the ID in the `wp_posts` table.

What I am trying to achieve is to retrieve the posts that do not have a tag associated with them which should mean that they do not have a record in the relationship table.

Here is the SQL I have tried:

```
SELECT *
  FROM wp_posts
  JOIN wp_term_relationships
    ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
 WHERE NOT EXISTS( 
SELECT * FROM wp_term_relationships 
      )
```

I believe that this syntax should work for what im trying to do but I am getting 0 results even though there are posts that do not have tags associated with them.

Can anyone help with where I am going wrong?

Comment: exists(t) means there is a row in t. You don't want 'where not exits a row in wp_term_relationships'. Please give a [mre]. But this question seems to be an easily found faq.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`/`WHERE` or `NOT EXISTS`.  For example:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM wp_posts p LEFT JOIN
     wp_term_relationships tr
     ON p.ID = tr.object_id LEFT JOIN
     tags t
     ON t.id = tr.term_taxonomy_id AND
        t.name = ?
WHERE t.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by either using a `left join` or a `not exists` (`left join` should be faster):

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
   ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
WHERE wp_term_relationships.object_id is null
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts wp
WHERE not exists(select * from wp_term_relationships where object_id = wp.ID)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i am getting results, however, the post-type on these do not appear to be posts. I then took tags out of a couple of posts and ran your query again and the results number did not change. Should we be checking the object_id is null because it will never be null as object_id will always have a value as this is the table that has the post ids with tags associated with them

Comment: But if there is no entry in the relationship table for a post, there won’t be any matching object_id found (which is why the check for null object_id).

Comment: When you remove all tags from a post, I am assuming there is no entry left for that post in the relationship table, which your description also indicates. 
Can you please verify for the post from which you removed the tags?

Comment: So, got this code that is displaying all posts and pages with Craigavon,Uk and all tags associated with them:                                                       SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.id, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_type, wp_terms.name FROM wp_posts, wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy, wp_terms WHERE wp_posts.id = wp_term_relationships.object_id AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy IN ('post_tag','wpfd-tag') AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id AND wp_terms.name IN('Craigavon', 'All', 'UK')

Comment: i now need to check for posts without tag and ive got it